# Round off and find minimum of a double value in list or map

Tags: java

I need to round of these values to 4 digits and insert it into List or Map and find the lowest value to be printed.

```
{0.37677792283166867, 0.4392472911358186, 0.37677792283166867}
```

i rounded of by

```
double value = Math.round(data * 10000.0) / 10000.0;
```

and also

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(data);
bd = bd.setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
double value = bd.doubleValue();
```

but i got result as

```
{0.3768, 0.43920000000000003, 0.3768}
```

the second data is rounded off like this in both cases

and i tried to find the minimum of these values stored in arraylist

```
double minIndex = list.indexOf(Collections.min(list));
```

but my output was 0.

Answer (score 0):

One of alternative ways is before you insert those values into `List` or `Map` , you may need help of `java.text.DecimalFormat`. Example :

`double value` = 0.43920000000000003;

```
 DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(".####");
 String result = decimalFormat.format (value); // you will need to parse it again to double
 System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(result));
```

And for finding minimum value :

```
    Double array []= {0.37677792283166867, 0.4392472911358186, 0.37677792283166867};
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
     double IndexOfMinimumValue = list.indexOf(Collections.min(list));
    System.out.println(list.indexOf(Collections.min(list)));
```

Of course it will print `0`, as minimum value is on `index-0`. And if you want the minimum value also be output then  `System.out.println(IndexOfMinimumValue +", minimum value = "+Collections.min(list));`